# How to group by multiple column values in pandas and apply a ifelse to impute/calculate values

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df like below

```
Node COMMODITY_CODE DAY Capacity_Case  Capacity_Delivery case_ratio deliveries_ratio  window_count
7014.0      SCFZ    1   26610.0         12.0                0.357854    0.354839.            3
7014.0      SCFZ    2   25551.0         11.0                0.457945    0.423077             3
7014.0      SCFZ    3   30669.0         13.0                0.283379    0.258621             3
7030.0      SCDD    1   34244.0         16.0                0.316505    0.300000             4
7030.0      SCDD    2   25954.0         13.0                0.236513    0.232558             4
```

I want to group by Node, DAY, COMMODITY_CODE and apply a ifelse function that to impute values for null records.
Here my conditions are the following:

1. For the group (Node, DAY, COMMODITY_CODE)

   1. if delivery_ratio is null
      then i want to replace with mean(delivery_ratio) for group and assign it to delivery_ratio_filled
   2. if case_ratio is null
      then i want to replace with mean(case_ratio) for group and assign it to case_ratio_filled
2. If for the group(Node, DAY, COMMODITY_CODE),

   1. delivery_ratio_filled is null, then assign 1/window_count value to it
   2. case_ratio_filled is null, then assign 1/window_count to it

I have accomplished this in R with ease using the dplyr package, I would basically like the same in Python using pandas.

```
df %>%
group_by(Node, DAY_OF_WK, COMMODITY_CODE) %>%
  mutate(delivery_ratio_filled = ifelse(!is.na(delivery_ratio),
                               delivery_ratio, 
                               mean(delivery_ratio)),
         case_ratio_filled = ifelse(!is.na(case_ratio),
                               case_ratio, 
                               mean(case_ratio))) %>%
  mutate(delivery_ratio_filled = ifelse(!is.na(delivery_ratio_filled),
                               delivery_ratio_filled,
                               1.0 / window_count),
         case_ratio_filled = ifelse(!is.na(case_ratio_filled),
                               case_ratio_filled,
                               1.0 / window_count))
```

Comment: What are your conditions and your desired output?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny updated the question with the desired conditions

Comment: For the test data, what is the current output and the expected output?

Comment: Your example data contains invalid floats and doesn't contain all cases to test the conditions (there is no `na` value in the columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the example input data doesn't contain `na` values (or groups larger than one item) that would be replaced with computed values. So the new columns are simple copies of the original columns.

The first conditions can be tested with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and applied to every row with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

```
df[['delivery_ratio_filled','case_ratio_filled']] = (
    df.groupby(['Node', 'DAY', 'COMMODITY_CODE'])[['deliveries_ratio','case_ratio']]
      .transform(
        lambda x: np.where(x.isna(), x.mean(), x)))
```

The second conditions don't need to be grouped

```
df['delivery_ratio_filled'] = (
  np.where(df['delivery_ratio_filled'].isna(),
           1 / df['window_count'],
           df['delivery_ratio_filled']))
df['case_ratio_filled'] = (
  np.where(df['case_ratio_filled'].isna(),
           1 / df['window_count'],
           df['case_ratio_filled']))
df
```

Out:

```
     Node COMMODITY_CODE  ...  delivery_ratio_filled  case_ratio_filled
0  7014.0           SCFZ  ...               0.354839           0.357854
1  7014.0           SCFZ  ...               0.423077           0.457945
2  7014.0           SCFZ  ...               0.258621           0.283379
3  7030.0           SCDD  ...               0.300000           0.316505
4  7030.0           SCDD  ...               0.232558           0.236513
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the `dplyr` way in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, group_by, mutate, if_else, is_na, mean
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.Node, f.COMMODITY_CODE, f.DAY, f.Capacity_Case,  f.Capacity_Delivery, f.case_ratio, f.delivery_ratio,  f.window_count,
...     7014.0, "SCFZ",           1,     26610.0,          12.0,                0.357854,     0.354839,          3,
...     7014.0, "SCFZ",           2,     25551.0,          11.0,                0.457945,     0.423077,          3,
...     7014.0, "SCFZ",           3,     30669.0,          13.0,                0.283379,     0.258621,          3,
...     7030.0, "SCDD",           1,     34244.0,          16.0,                0.316505,     0.300000,          4,
...     7030.0, "SCDD",           2,     25954.0,          13.0,                0.236513,     0.232558,          4,
... )    
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df >> \
...     group_by(f.Node, f.DAY, f.COMMODITY_CODE) >> \
...     mutate(delivery_ratio_filled = if_else(~is_na(f.delivery_ratio),
...                                            f.delivery_ratio, 
...                                            mean(f.delivery_ratio)),
...            case_ratio_filled = if_else(~is_na(f.case_ratio),
...                                        f.case_ratio, 
...                                        mean(f.case_ratio))) >> \
...     mutate(delivery_ratio_filled = if_else(~is_na(f.delivery_ratio_filled),
...                                            f.delivery_ratio_filled,
...                                            1.0 / f.window_count),
...            case_ratio_filled = if_else(~is_na(f.case_ratio_filled),
...                                        f.case_ratio_filled,
...                                        1.0 / f.window_count))
       Node COMMODITY_CODE     DAY  Capacity_Case  Capacity_Delivery  case_ratio  delivery_ratio  window_count  delivery_ratio_filled  case_ratio_filled
  <float64>       <object> <int64>      <float64>          <float64>   <float64>       <float64>       <int64>              <float64>          <float64>
0    7014.0           SCFZ       1        26610.0               12.0    0.357854        0.354839             3               0.354839           0.357854
1    7014.0           SCFZ       2        25551.0               11.0    0.457945        0.423077             3               0.423077           0.457945
2    7014.0           SCFZ       3        30669.0               13.0    0.283379        0.258621             3               0.258621           0.283379
3    7030.0           SCDD       1        34244.0               16.0    0.316505        0.300000             4               0.300000           0.316505
4    7030.0           SCDD       2        25954.0               13.0    0.236513        0.232558             4               0.232558           0.236513

[Groups: Node, DAY, COMMODITY_CODE (n=5)]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.